# What a person is called who left most of the thing (or everything) incomplete ? Is there any single word for it?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A person who has a habit of leaving everything or most of the things incomplete, due to any reason. Is there any word of this kind of habit or person having this habit ?

Comment: You need to be more precise. Do they consciously quit (perhaps have a fear of finishing)? Lose interest? Get distracted and forget about it? You can't say "due to any reason" and expect a word that encompasses every reason.

Answer (score 1):

procrastinator, the noun form of procrastinate (to put off intentionally the doing of something that should be done), e.g., someone who spends too much time on stack exchange websites

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procrastinator

Answer (score -1):

I think one term could be a [slacker](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slacker).

Comment: Hi Mary, welcome to ELU.SE! If you want to leave a single suggested word answer like this, it helps if you include a link to a reputable online dictionary for others to follow up on, and determine if it fits their need too. I'll edit your post so you have an example.